# Java - Will the application still run after USB eject

Tags: java, usb

Hello stackoverflow users,

I am here with a very simple question. The title might say it all, but let me explain it again:
I have an application that is on my USB flash drive. When I run the application from the USB flash drive will it keep running even when I eject the USB from my laptop?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried doing it?

Comment: I don't have my USB with me right now, and I haven't tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not at all a simple question; as it depends on many factors.

First of all, any decent operating system will **refuse** to eject "removable media" while that thing is still **in use**.

Meaning: you can't *eject* it (as that is a process where the OS "signs off" a resource).

In that sense, your question doesn't make sense.

In case you are asking: what happens when I just rip out the USB media without properly ejecting; all kinds of things can happen - depending on the exact circumstances.

Example: when you only have class files on the stick - chances are that the JVM will keep running until your application requires a class that wasn't previously loaded. Then the class loader will realize: that drive is gone, and the JVM will most likely crash.

Answer (score 1):

A possible annoying situation I've seen is the system ejects/dismounts the USB drive (possibly as a response to the drive drawing too much power).

I've seen classloader exceptions even when the drive is subsequently remounted when the JVM tries to load a class it needs. Whilst the JVM won't have crashed it is unlikely your program will be able to do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

It will not keep running unless you have the application itself downloaded onto the computer and if the files you are using are all at the same location.